# split dvb url address into separate values

Tags: c, string, parsing, dvb

Let assume we have such URL:

```
dvb://1.3f3.255c.15
```

my question is how to parse this address in following way:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 3f3
val3 = 255c
val4 = 15
```

First idea is to use `strchr()` from standard C library, but maybe done it before. I would like to make it as simple as possible. When I will succeed I will put my solution.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

```
char dvb_url[] = "dvb://1.3f3.255c.15";

//Begin stripping the scheme (dvb:/)
char *tokenized = strtok(dvb_url, "/");
//Finish stripping scheme
tokenized = strtok(NULL, "/.");

while(tokenized != NULL)
{
    //Store in variable here            
    printf("%s\n", tokenized);
    tokenized = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```

Comment: Be aware that strtok will modify the original string replacing the tokenized characters with `\0`. If you would like to maintain the orignal string consider a `memcpy` or `memmove`. (note: If the scheme is missing (dvb://) it would fail)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple answer if your pattern is fixed. I don't how many people use it like this.

`sscanf()` is very handy here :)

```
char *dvb_string = "dvb://1.3f3.255c.15";
char proto[10], output1[10], output2[10], output3[10], output4[10];
sscanf(dvb_string, "%[^:]://%[^.].%[^.].%[^.].%s", proto, output1, output2, output3, output4);
fprintf(stderr, "%s -- > %s %s %s %s %s\n", dvb_string, proto, output1, output2, output3, output4);
```

### OUTPUT:

```
dvb://1.3f3.255c.15 -- > dvb 1 3f3 255c 15
```

Simple as this :) enjoy C.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the `strchr()` function is handy enough:

```
char *str = "dvb://1.3f3.255c.15";
char val[10][256];
char *cur = str;
int i = 0;

for ( ; cur = strchr(str, '.'); cur != NULL && i < 10)
{
    strncpy(val[i], cur, 256);
    if(strchr(val[i], '.') != NULL)
        strchr(val[i], '.') = '\0';
    ++i;
}
```

You should end up with your values in `val[0 to N]`.